# Generate Select instead of Input

Tags: jquery, select, input, replace

**Due to restrictions of editing some of my templates I really need your help with:**

1. generate a select list with
   predefined options instead of input
   field
2. input field to be hidden after
   select is generated
3. when some option selected transfer
   that option's value into that hidden
   input

---

**I provide some HTML to be more clear:**

*This is what we've got in the template before jQuery is applied:*

```
<input type="text" id="myId" name="myName" value="">
```

*This is what we need it to be after jQuery is applied*

```
<select id="mySelect">
   <option>a</option>
   <option>b</option>
   <option>c</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="myId" name="myName" value="" style="display:none">
```

**Please note:** I need to predefine options value and their quantity. Select must be generated right where input field was.

**Also**: I also really need to generate two or more select lists in some templates and transfer selected option's values consistently into one input.

Example:

```
   <select id="mySelect1">
     <option>a</option>
   </select>

   <select id="mySelect2">
     <option>b</option>
   </select>

   <input type="text" id="myId" name="myName" value="a b" style="display:none"> //a + b added
```

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Hide your input box:

   $("#myId").hide();
2. Dynamically generate a select-Box:

> ```
> var select = "<select onchange=\"$('#myId').val(this.value);\">"+
>              "<option value=\"a\">a</option>" +
>              "<option value=\"b\">b</option>" +
>              "<option value=\"c\">c</option>" +
>              "</select>";
> ```

1. Insert this box before or after you input-box:

> $(select).insertBefore($("#myId"));

or

> $(select).insertAfter($("#myId"));

Comment: Is there any chance to make option list with using <option> tag just once? Then we can list the options in jQuery. And when select will be created it will automatically be filled with defined quantity of option names. And those names will be automatically duplicated to the value and between option tag. Hope I made myself clear enough. Thanks

Comment: somth like that (sorry for markup)

var = $ourvalue
("a","b","c","d")

<option value=\"$ourvalue\">$ourvalue</option>